Can't connect to a Bluetooth device
I'm trying to connect to a MLT board (Arduino) via Bluetooth from Android, but I get the same error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
...
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
...
Caused by: java.io.IOException: read failed, socket might closed or timeout, read ret: -1
Here's the code that searches and successfully adds the nearby devices to a LinearLayout:

class ScanBActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private var bluetoothAdapter: BluetoothAdapter? = null
    private lateinit var bSocket: BluetoothSocket
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_scan_bactivity)

        val filter = IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND)
        registerReceiver(discoveryReceiver, filter)
        val scanButton = findViewById<Button>(R.id.scanBtn)
        scanButton.setOnClickListener { discoverDevices() }
        val bluetoothManager = getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
        bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
    }

    private val savedDevices = mutableSetOf<String>()

    private fun discoverDevices() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        if (bluetoothAdapter?.isDiscovering == true) {
            bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()
        }
        bluetoothAdapter?.startDiscovery()
    }

    private val discoveryReceiver: BroadcastReceiver = object : BroadcastReceiver() {
        override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
            val action = intent.action
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND == action) {
                val device =
                    intent.getParcelableExtra<BluetoothDevice>(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE)
                val deviceAddress = device?.address
                if (deviceAddress != null) {
                    savedDevices.add(deviceAddress)
                }
                val deviceName = try {
                    device?.name ?: "Unknown Device"
                } catch (securityException: SecurityException) {
                    Log.e("ScanActivity", "Permission not granted for accessing device name")
                }
                val deviceInfo = "$deviceName\n$deviceAddress"
                val deviceButton = Button(this@ScanBActivity)
                deviceButton.text = deviceInfo
                deviceButton.setOnClickListener {
                    // Handle click event - connect to the device
                    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                            this@ScanBActivity,
                            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
                        ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        return@setOnClickListener
                    }
                    if (deviceAddress != null) {
                        connectToDevice(deviceAddress)

                    }
                }

                val linearLayout = findViewById<LinearLayout>(R.id.linLayout)
                linearLayout?.addView(deviceButton)

                linearLayout?.invalidate()
            }
        }
    }

    fun connectToDevice(deviceAddress : String) {
        val bDev = bluetoothAdapter?.getRemoteDevice(deviceAddress)
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        if (bDev != null) {
            bSocket = bDev.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"))
        }
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                this,
                Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN
            ) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        ) {
            return
        }
        bluetoothAdapter?.cancelDiscovery()

        bSocket?.let { socket ->
            Log.d("MYLOG", "trying to connect")
            socket.connect()

        }
    }

    private fun sendDataTO(socket : BluetoothSocket) {

    }

}```

Tryed to create InsecureRFcommSocket, change the UUID.. still the same error
I want to connect to the device and send byteArrays from another Activity where all my data edits are placed. 

